# How to use Kotlin Coroutines with an onSuccessListner?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**Android app dev in Kotlin**

I have two functions F1 and F2, which have basically the same structure. I want them to return a String.
I want to use them like this:

```
// In some other function, say F3

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){

    val result1: Deferred<String> = async(Dispatchers.Main) { F1(img) }
    val result2: Deferred<String> = async(Dispatchers.Main) { F2(img) }

    doSomething(result1.await(), result2.await())
}
```

---

```
// funcion F1:

suspend fun F1(img: Bitmap): Deferred<String>{
    obj.process(img)
        .addOnSuccessListner{ result ->
            // result is the string to be returned as Deferred
        }
}

// function F2, same structure as F1

suspend fun F2(img: Bitmap): Deferred<String>{
    obj.process(img)
        .addOnSuccessListner{ result ->
            // result is the string to be returned as Deferred
        }
}
```

---

I want to run F1 and F2 in parallel using Kotlin Coroutines, but I am stumped at the moment as to how to restructure F1 and F2 for the F3 code to work. Would appreciate some help doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `Deferred` one time too many: both as the return value of `async` and explicitly as the return value of the functions. You should do it as follows:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val result1: Deferred<String> = async { F1(img) }
        val result2: Deferred<String> = async { F2(img) }
        doSomething(result1.await(), result2.await())
    }
}

suspend fun F1(img: Bitmap): String = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    obj.process(img)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            cont.resume(result)
        }
}

suspend fun F2(img: Bitmap): String = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    obj.process(img)
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            cont.resume(result)
        }
}
```

This code transformed your listener-based API into a simple `suspend fun` that you just call and get its result in the return value.

You can still use `async` to parallelize the two invocations.

And the usual advice: look into structured concurrency and use something better than `GlobalScope`. This way will work for most scenarios, but it will be prone to leaks. When going that way, you should also use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` so the coroutines in progress can get gracefully cancelled and cleaned up.

Comment: Thank you so much, this cleared my doubt. Yes, I will change the GlobalScope to something more leak-proof.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) is what you're looking for.
In your case, for example:

```
suspend fun F1(img: Bitmap) = suspendCoroutine<String> {
    obj.process(img)
        .addOnSuccessListner{ result ->
            it.resume(result)
        }
}
```

You might need ***suspendCancellableCoroutine*** as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I did what you said, but it highlights an error on passing "result" as a parameter to "it.resume". It says required is Deferred<String> but found String.

Comment: Ah, you want your function return String, right? So you should remove "Deferred" in your code.